# Django-storages : Keeping a cached version locally to increase read speed

Tags: django, python-django-storages

With Django-storages, is it possible to keep a cached version locally for subsequent requests?

I'm trying to read few large files (~10 mb) on user request. 
Since I'm using elastic-beanstalk and multiple instances, I've to keep them on S3.

Those files are updated using an external script. Django app only reads them.

Comment: What are these files that you are serving and why do you want to cache them?

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm not serving them to the user. They are trained model files. I need them to predict some values for each request. Training is done by an external script.

Comment: How often does the model change and how is your app deployed? (many workers spread over multiple machines or a single VM)